# Named-only arguments when subclassing in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to add an optional named argument to a subclass' constructor. When not specified, the arguments should be the same as for the underlying superclass. E.g.

```
class Foo(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                print 'args', args
                print 'kwargs', kwargs


class Bar(Foo):
        # Here I want hello to be named-only, so that passing `hello` would be
        # optional, and all arguments would otherwise be passed to `Foo`.
        # However, such a syntax is incorrect
        #def __init__(self, *args, hello=False, **kwargs):
        #        Foo.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # I can do this instead. But this always requires passing `hello` as
        # the first argument
        def __init__(self, hello=False, *args, **kwargs):
                Foo.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


# Prints `args (2, 3)` and `kwargs {'for_foo': 4}`, but I want args to be
# `(1, 2, 3)` instead and 'hello` to be `False` instead of `1`
f = Bar(1, 2, 3, for_foo=4)

# This wouldn't work at all, since `hello` is passed twice. I want args
# to be printed as `(1, 2, 3)` again, and `hello` to be `True` and retained
# by `Bar.__init__`
f = Bar(1, 2, 3, hello=True)
```

Is there a pattern for such cases? What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            hello = kwargs.pop('hello')
        except KeyError:
            hello = False
        Foo.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: ...or one could use a similar solution from the linked question which does not use exception handling (and thus may be faster)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting "hello" from kwargs. If it is there, remove it and pass smaller kwargs to superclass constructor, else just call superclass constructor:

```
#in Bar:
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    hello = None
    if "hello" in kwargs:
        hello = kwargs["hello"]
        del kwargs["hello"]
    Foo.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    if not hello is None:
        do_something_with_hello(hello)
```